# Is there any way to get 'Recent messages' while commiting using svn command line in windows

Tags: svn, cmd

As all of you must be aware, that when we commit using TortoiseSVN client on Windows, we get 'Recent Messages' option which if clicked opens the 'Log History' window. We can select any message from this log history. I want this same functionality to work using svn.exe command-line client.

Could you please help me in getting this working?

Comment: you may accept and/or upvote the answer which helped you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is no such feature in `svn` command-line client AFAIK. Recent log entries is the feature of TortoiseSVN. Other GUI clients may also have it but not the command-line client.

I guess that you can specify [`--editor-cmd` argument or `editor-cmd` runtime config option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.editor_cmd) to run external log entry editor which will save your recent log messages for later reuse.

```
--editor-cmd CMD

Specifies an external program to use to edit a log message or a property value.
See the editor-cmd section in the section called “Config” for ways to specify
a default editor.
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using Windows, you have all the power of PowerShell available to you. I wrote a small suite of PowerShell tools to analyze Subversion meta-data; using my `Get-SvnLog` cmdlet this will provide what you are looking for:

```
Get-SvnLog | ? { $_.Date -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | select -ExpandProperty Message
```

That is, it finds all svn log entries within the last thirty days (adjust to a number of your liking) and reports the commit message for each of those commits. Under the covers, `Get-SvnLog` uses the command-line svn tools to query the SVN repository, then converts that output into PowerShell objects, so you have the full repertoire of PowerShell to manipulate that data.

You can see the API for `Get-SvnLog` in my [open source bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html), which also includes 20 other example recipes. Open the PowerShell "book" and go to SvnTools. Download the code [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html).

Comment: Very helpful stuff! But it doesn't act like TortoiseSVN's recent log entries (tsvn caches log entries of uncomitted changes).

Comment: Are your Posh SvnTools related to http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Subversion-PowerShell-bbd1db40 ?

Comment: No, my SvnTools are unrelated to the other library you mention.